# Drawing text over a bufferedimage on a panel

Tags: java, swing, text, label, awt

I am writing a program that consists of three different panels.

This is part of my bottom panel. I display an image using BufferedImage, and I would like to create some text that will appear around 350px into the image, and 15px down. I cannot manage to get this to work and overlay over the bufferedImage.

My current code is as follows (For the bottom panel):

```
public class BtmPanel extends JPanel {
    BtmPanel(){
        try {
            JLabel imgLabel = new JLabel();
            final BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("image.png"));
            ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(img);
            imgLabel.setIcon(icon);
            this.add(imgLabel);
        }
        catch(IOException ie){
            System.out.println("image does not exist");
        }
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawString("Y:  " + MiddlePanel.y ,350,15);
    }
}
```

Comment: To understand why your code doesn't work read the section from the Swing tutorial on [A Closer Look at the Painting Mechanism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/closer.html). The problem is the label is painted on top of the panel, so it overwrites the custom painting of the panel. You could extend JLabel to do the custom painting. Also, why are you using magic numbers? How are 350 and 15 relevant. There could be other options like adding a JLabel to the JLable and use a layout manager to position the text.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways you might achieve this, depending on your needs and desires.

For example, rather than using a `JLabel` to display the image, you could paint it directly yourself, for example...

```
public class BtmPanel extends JPanel {
    private BufferedImage image;
    BtmPanel(){
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(new File("image.png"));
        }
        catch(IOException ie){
            System.out.println("image does not exist");
        }
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (image != null) {
            g.drawImage(0, 0, image, this);
        }
        g.drawString("Y:  " + MiddlePanel.y ,350,15);
    }
}
```

The reason for doing it this way is you don't (really) control the placement of the image within a `JLabel` (lots of things can affect it's positioning).

Another solution would be to draw the text directly onto the `BufferedImage` itself.  Which you would use would depend on how dynamic the text might be and a bunch of other factors

Answer (score -1):

A way to do this is doing the exact inverse of your example, overriding the JPanel's paint method painting a BufferedImage (creating a background with your image), and then you can normally add the JLabel with text on your JPanel extension.

Please note that if JPanel is resized and you don't want to have a bad quality background, you'll have to manually create a resized version to adapt the container, or, at least, resize your buffered image with a little logic to keep Width/Height ratio... not that easy! 
For the basic version you can try something like the following (taken from a working example) paintComponent overridden function:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    Image background = backgroundImage.getScaledInstance(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);

    super.paintComponent(g);
    if (backgroundImage != null) {
        g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: (1-) you should NOT be reading the Image in the paintComponent() method. You don't want to read the image every time the component needs to be repainted.

Comment: I did this (or, better, a more complex version of this I didn't paste here to keep answer simple) because i needed to resize when user resized the container, but yes, a better approach should be to use a window listener and not repaint method... but this did the trick for me and works great, even if it's not a perfect solution. So, sorry if I did not copy-paste my full solution :)

Comment: If you need to resize to fill the window you can just use: `g.drawImage(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null)`. There is no need for a WindowListener or to create a scaled image each time.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! So.. can you explain me what's the difference in your solution from manually resize image before to paint it? Is there any real performance difference between manually resizing an image and paint it as it is (as I used to), and resize it with paint method? I've always thought there was no real pratical difference in code executed by JVM.. is it a code style good practice to you? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't know if there is any real difference. But you are doing extra work. You have to create the Image and paint onto the image. And then you paint the image to the panel, so you are doing the painting twice.

Comment: This is a thing I don't understand, I've only assigned an Image variable and then use it to call a drawImage() one time... and, furthermore, this way I can even choose the resize algorithm, that sounds great to me, even if I am not sure of performance differences between your solution and mine.

Comment: You have two references to the image. You have the original image. Then you invoke a method to create a scaled instance of the image. The original image has to be scaled and painted onto the new image. Then you have to paint that image onto the panel. Who knows, the drawImage(...) method may do exactly the same thing behind the scenes, but it will release the resources when the painting method is finished. In your case you will always be keeping two copies of the image in memory.

Comment: Also, the point is you have changed the context of the whole question. The original question was using a JLabel. A JLabel always paints the image at its real size without scaling. By adding the scaling you increased the complexity of the answer. You may know what you are doing and why, but it is not what the question was about.